# Detect if update query is from a trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have the table named `pledgeRating` that stores user ratings. On every insert I run the below trigger to update `ratingsCount` and `rating` columns in the `pledgeTemplate` table:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`trigger`@`%` TRIGGER `project87`.`pledgeRating_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `pledgeRating` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE `pledgeTemplate` 
        SET `rating` = ((`rating` * `ratingsCount`) + NEW.rating) / (`ratingsCount` + 1),
            `ratingsCount` = `ratingsCount` + 1
        WHERE `id` = NEW.pledgeTemplateID;
END
```

For the sake of completeness I want to prevent all mysql users from updating directly the `ratingsCount` and `rating` columns in the `pledgeTemplate` table. I want those two columns to be updated only from the trigger.

To achieve that I have created a new trigger in the `pledgeTemplate` table to validate a user running the update query, but I cannot find a way to detect if that update is from a trigger or not:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`trigger`@`%` TRIGGER `project87`.`pledgeTemplate_BEFORE_UPDATE` BEFORE UPDATE ON `pledgeTemplate` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (OLD.ratingsCount != NEW.ratingsCount OR OLD.rating != NEW.rating) AND {{Update query is not from the trigger}} THEN
        SIGNAL sqlstate '45000' SET message_text = 'Error: Only trigger can modify ratingsCount or rating columns';
    END IF;
END
```

Is it possible to pass a flag from the first trigger so I can detect in the second trigger if the query came from the trigger or not? I have looked in to the `CURRENT_USER` object and `USER()` function as I thought that these may be helpful. However the `CURRENT_USER` is always whatever is set to the `DEFINER` and `USER()` always return a user that runs the initial query.

So, is there any way to detect if an update query on the `pledgeTemplate` table runs from a trigger or "direct" update?

Comment: I dont think it`s possible,but you could remove UPDATE permission on the respective table for your users

Comment: The thing is that I still need my users to update the `pledgeTemplate` table. If I remove UPDATE permission then I will stop all updates. I just want to protect those two columns from being updated other than from a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Hello_

first I started to explain my idea in a comment but seems that It became too long and not well formatted. So this is just an idea, I don't know if you are fine with it but I will share it:

1. `ALTER TABLE pledgeTemplate ADD COLUMN isTriggerUpdate BIT NULL DEFAULT 0;` - so we add a column in the table, that we can use as flag to determine if the update is coming from the trigger or user

2.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`trigger`@`%` TRIGGER `project87`.`pledgeRating_AFTER_INSERT` 
AFTER INSERT ON `pledgeRating` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE `pledgeTemplate` 
        SET `rating` = ((`rating` * `ratingsCount`) + NEW.rating) / (`ratingsCount` + 1),
            `ratingsCount` = `ratingsCount` + 1,
            `isTriggerUpdate ` = 1
        WHERE `id` = NEW.pledgeTemplateID;
END
```

Change the code of your trigger **pledgeRating_AFTER_INSERT** to set the flag column to true

3.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`trigger`@`%` TRIGGER `project87`.`pledgeTemplate_BEFORE_UPDATE` 
BEFORE UPDATE ON `pledgeTemplate` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (OLD.ratingsCount != NEW.ratingsCount OR OLD.rating != NEW.rating) 
       AND NEW.isTriggerUpdate != 1 THEN
        SIGNAL sqlstate '45000' SET message_text = 'Error: Only trigger can modify ratingsCount or rating columns';
    END IF;
END
```

Now you can have the missing condition in **pledgeTemplate_BEFORE_UPDATE** like this.

I think this will work as logic, but the question is, is this the most efficient logic to implement this. In this logic you have not to expose **isTriggerUpdate** column to front end in any case, because simply setting it to true will bypass this logic ...

Good Luck!